# Laravel Route - auth:api optional

Tags: laravel

Currently I am using `auth:api` in some routes.
If I don't use it; then I can not get "user information".
If I use it, you have to be authorized with user, or it'll return error.

But I want to make it optional.
If I am logged in, then i'll return some extra information, if not I won't do it.

Couldn't find any way to make it optional.

```
Route::namespace('Contact')->middleware(['auth:api'])->
```

You have to be logged in to reach that route.

```
Route::namespace('Product')->group(function () {
```

You can not get user information even if you're authorized by bearer token.

Comment: As the only answer to this question is saying, you have to get the user anyway, it will just return `null` if there is no valid token set, so no user could be get. If auth is optional, then the route is public, meaning you do not add any `auth` middleware to it

Answer (score 2):

If there's a valid token in the `Authorization` header, `$request->user('api')` will return the authenticated user. Or if you don't use `Request`, you can simply do:

```
\Auth::guard('api')->user()
```

If there's no token, or the token is invalid, it will return null. This behavior is independent of whether you're using the `auth:api` middleware or not.

### Explaining

When you called `$request->user()` it was actually `$request->user('web')` and while you use `auth:api`, Laravel will then use the `api` guard as the default. That's why it worked when using `auth:api` middleware but didn't work when delete it.